# Are shims alone sufficient for leveling out a shelving unit?

Tags: shelving, leveling

I have an IKEA Kallax unit (3x4) that I plan to place in a room of my house that unfortunately is not level. Right now, I've placed some wood shims underneath the downslope side (~1" difference) to level out the shelving unit. I also plan to secure the unit to the wall once I've finalized everything. My question is, are the shims enough? Or should I be considering adding additional supports, and if so, what do you recommend? See pictures below for reference. If it makes a difference, the unit will be full of board games. [image: Close up view] [image: Whole shelf view]

Comment: Seems to be a lot of slope for three/four feet of floor.  Board games should be okay, something heavy like bowling balls might want more support.  Are you levelling it out to match the wall lines?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a back to the unit., and as stated, 1 inch of slope for such little run doesn't sound right.  Could the unit be racked, ( not built square) and this is why it is not showing level?

Comment: Sure, but that's not how you use shims. They should all be opposite-facing each other - ending up 'flat'. - Also, that looks like a 12" long piece of one-by should just go there. Or a 2x4, and then you shim the other side. ... (An inch and an eighth? you need a length of five-quarters board, not one-by. But GL finding any tho. ... Or use two, one-bys... and maybe still some shims). - How you have it would be fine if you set it all with some construction adhesive. Except that will mar the floor. This is your IKEA BS somewhere; not a kitchen cabinet that *will* exist and be covered with a skirt.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to shim the entire gap, front, middle and back, three sets of shims. Ikea furniture is not usually solid wood so a bow or sag is likely to develop. You could try to mask the longer shims by coloring them with a scratch cover crayon so they would not be as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I have a seriously tilted corner in my dining room, so it does happen -- when houses settle they don't do so evenly and the house itself can get racked. First step is to make sure the proper columns have been added to the house so it doesn't continue to get worse. After that...

My solution, since my display cabinet rests its weight on its ends, was to cut a custom wedge for each end out of a 2x2 with a mitered L corner to go around the front corner of the box **[*]**, trim their width to match the feet, and stain them to match the cabinet. Unless I point it out, nobody notices the wedge; it just looks like part of the foot with a decorative shadow line.

[image: long view of display cabinet, now level and plumb]
[image: medium view of lower left corner of cabinet]
[image: close up of corner showing wedge piece matched to corner]
[image: close up of side showing that wedge extends fully front to back]

Note the thickness of this wedge. This is the lower end so it needed to be built up more; the high end is much thinner and has a different slope. Also note that the stain and wood are not an exact match, but are close enough for this purpose.

**[*]:** I originally wrote 2x6. Nope. I did this the proper/cheap way.

Carpentry (and not even finish carpentry) rather than fine woodworking/cabinetry. But it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add shims below the two vertical boards in the middle as well.  Either front, middle, and back as suggested above, or just a single piece under each vertical board.  That's the only support that matters for the upper shelves, and should easily be enough for the bottom board as well.

I'd go farther than just putting them there, though, I'd either glue or screw pieces of wood of the right thickness in place, recessing screws so they don't scratch the floor.  Adding stick-on felt pads would also help protect the floor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Ikea shelf but with a plinth so I used 4 of [these](https://www.rockler.com/adjustable-corner-support) and it held up to heavy use for years.

Yours doesn't have a plinth so maybe you could fit [these](https://www.rockler.com/adjustable-supports) or if not, perhaps just [these](https://www.rockler.com/combination-leg-equalizer).  You have to know where the strength of the bottom shelf is and attach to that, not just anywhere.  But the corners are a good bet